# What does the $x$ represent in the vector form of a line $(x = p + td)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

The vector form equation of a line is: $x = p + td$

I know that $p$ is a point which lies on the line, and $d$ is a directional vector. $t$ is a scalar, and it serves to show that there are infinitely many possible values of $d$, since as long as the vector is parallel to the line it can serve as d.

But, and this might be a stupid question, what does the $x$ represent? In a pre-calculus context I'd see the equation $y = mx + b$ and I know is the $x$ coordinate of a point that is on that line. But in the case of the vector form, $x$ is a vector. Does it mean that $x$ is a vector on the line?

Any help is appreciated. And if I stated anything that please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

The vector equation x= p+ td where "p is a point which lies on the line, and d is a directional vector" is essentially the sum of two vectors.  Although the problem **says** "p is a point" in the equation it is actually being treated as the vector from the origin of some coordinate system to the point.  Similarly x is, strictly speaking, a vector from the origin to the point but is being treated as being that point.

This is what is often called the "position vector" of a point.  In a three dimensional coordinate system, "(x, y, z)" represents a point.  In some text books, it is also used to represent the vector from the origin to that point.  I prefer to distinguish "vector" from "point" as many (if not most) textbooks do, using $\left<x, y, z\right>$ to represent the vector from (0, 0, 0) to (x, y, z).  Since there is a "one-to-one correspondence" between points and their "position vectors" that is an "abuse of notation" that is not **too** abusive.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, and thanks for the help! You mentioned ⟨x,y,z⟩ as a way to differentiate between a point and a vector to that point, but would you say square brackets (i.e. [x,y,z]) can also be used for that purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $x$ is a vector on the line. You can think of $t$ as time and $p$ as the initial point so at some specific $t_0$ you'll get some specific $x_0$ which is where the vector defining the line will be at time $t_0$. This is easier to see if you draw a picture of these vectors using the geometric interpretation of scalar multiplication and addition but you've got the right idea.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘a vector on the line’?

Comment: @Bernard A vector on the line means they head of the vector is one a point that the line contains

Comment: This way of saying is ambiguous from my point of view.

Comment: @Bernard Well it's rather common so I expect you'll see it again.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, and this is a helpful way of thinking about this, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$x$ is not necessarily a vector: it is a point on the line, like $p$. Remember  an *affine space* is a non-empty set with a *simply transitive action* of a vector space. So the notation  $x=p+t\vec d$ means that $x$ is the point $p$ *translated by the vector* $t\vec d$.